# Check docker run in Gitlab CICD pipeline

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using [Gitlab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html) to build Docker images of our Node server.

I am wondering if there is a way to test that `docker run` of the image was ok.

We've had few occasions where the Docker builds but it is missing some files/env variables and it fails to start the server.

Is there any way to run the `docker` image and test if it is starting up correctly in the CI/CD pipeline?

Cheers.

Comment: Can't you add a step in the pipeline that runs the newly built container? After that add another step to run some end to end test cases to check the sanity of the container.

Comment: Thank you @asolanki My problem is how to detect the container started properly and then terminate it so that the test passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gitlab you are able to [use a docker-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#register-docker-runner).

> When you use the docker-runner, and not a shell runner, a docker-like
>   image and its services have to initiate, it should give an error if
>   something fails.

Chek [this docs from gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#register-docker-runner):

This is a classic `yml` from that web:

```
default:
  image:
    name: ruby:2.2
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]

  services:
  - name: my-postgres:9.4
    alias: db-postgres
    entrypoint: ["/usr/local/bin/db-postgres"]
    command: ["start"]

  before_script:
  - bundle install

test:
  script:
  - bundle exec rake spec
```

As you see, the test sections will be executed after building the image, so, you should not have to worry about. **Gitlab should detect any errors when loading the image**

> If you are [doing it with the shell gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html), you should call the
>   docker image start like this:

```
stages:
  - dockerStartup
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - dockerStop
job 0:
  stage: dockerStartup
  script:
    - docker build -t my-docker-image .
    - docker run my-docker-image /script/to/run/tests
[...] //your jobs here
job 5:
  stage: dockerStop
  script: docker stop whatever
```