# Gitlab-CI (under gitlab.com) "system failure" starting container process

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

This is my 1st try to set up a basic CI workflow on `gitlab.com`. The concerned project is a basic static website, and I wanted to run some `npm install` and `gulp build` directly on gitlab.

I created a `.gitlab-ci.yml`file, which is recognized and launched. But firsts implementations failed, so I came back to the more basic CI script ever, as follows:

```
image: debian:jessie

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building the app"
```

Even in this case I encounter the same error:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"gitlab-runner-build\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown (executor_docker.go:833:0s)
```

I tried with the following images: `debian:jessie`, `node:latest` & `busybox`.

How could I fix this issue please? Am I doing something wrong?

> **HINT**: Please, note that this is a Gitlab.com hosted instance. Not a
>   local one. The runner I'm using is hosted on Gitlab servers.

Full error message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:e498dabfee1c6735c9da947e0d438edd13593b7d721c989ba8ede14ab603b900 for node:latest ...

ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"gitlab-runner-build\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown (executor_docker.go:833:0s)
```

Comment: That error indicates a problem with the GitLab runner injecting itself into the container, if you are using their shared runners it will probably be fixed soon, try using another base image like `busybox`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried with `busybox`, same error...

Comment: one user says using stretch instead of jessie fixed their issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/27042#note_215660995

Comment: Did you installed the docker gitlab-runner???

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz Locally? I'm using gitlab.com, I've installed nothing.

Comment: Yeah, you should install your gitlab-runner locally if you want to run whatever locally. Gitlab is not able to run anything in your machine without it

Comment: Check this @paradise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229210/check-docker-run-in-gitlab-cicd-pipeline/58253166#58253166

Comment: "GitLab Runner is the open source project that is used to run your jobs and send the results back to GitLab. It is used in conjunction with GitLab CI, the open-source continuous integration service included with GitLab that coordinates the jobs" -> https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/

Comment: @paradise, do you have an online account?? nothing like a local runner?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz That's what I was trying to say :) Nothing related to gitlab runs locally. I only use my online account: I push my code on gitlab.com, then there I tried to setup up CI/CD.

Comment: @paradise  Check this -> Searching around shows that this is a Docker daemon issue.  Perhaps the gitlab.com shared runners need to get rebooted? - Are you able to restart the online runners from gitlab.com??? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3740

Comment: @paradise May you check your full logs?? look at this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1616

You should see the kind of a runner execution error before the Docker one.  Is it like this?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz So: yes I did found the links you provide, talking about this docker potential issue. I don't think that I can restart the runners on online instance, but I will investigate. And no I have no more information about the error; nothing like the issue you pointed out.

Comment: Maybe you should try to open a new issue to gitlab.com and if you are a (paying) customer, with more reason...  I think it's an internal issue with those particular runner/container versions... (as LuizFerraz pointed initially) Maybe @Arty-chan comment is ok and changing the image saves it

Comment: I.m going to make some tests if I’m able and I’ll tell you back

Answer (score 2):

I tested exactly your model in a fresh new project on `Gitlab.com`

**gitlab-ci.yml(debian)**

```
image: debian:jessie

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building the app"
```

My project is a default Node.js project on base, and I just changed the default `docker` gitlab-ci.yml in order to match yours.

My results are those ones:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
Using Docker executor with image debian:jessie ...
Pulling docker image debian:jessie ...
Using docker image sha256:c9d6adb06e4d1092f4dae842e41ba34566481ac002ad52102389122ea6969fd4 for debian:jessie ...
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-14701224-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1570489833-8fc7b7db...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/alejandroteixeiraconsultoria/my-awesome-response/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/alejandroteixeiraconsultoria/my-awesome-response
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Checking out 39d7cf97 as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Building the app"
Building the app
Job succeeded
```

As you will see, it went perfect.

The difference I see is this:

Mine:

> Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)   on docker-auto-scale
>   **ed2dce3a**

Yours:

> Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)   on docker-auto-scale
>   **fa6cab46**

If you go to shared runners section, just check that `ed2dce3a` and `fa6cab46` are the references for our runners.

[image]

If you now look carefully at the tags, you will see they are different: min is only `docker` and `gce` but yours has much more tags.

```
shared-runners-manager-6.gitlab.com 
shared-runners-manager-3.gitlab.com
```

As a second attempt, I tried to create a `node:latest` image with this gitlab-yml

**gitlab-ci.yml (node)**

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - echo "Building the app"
    - echo "Calling npm "
    - npm update
```

And the results were again succesful:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:e498dabfee1c6735c9da947e0d438edd13593b7d721c989ba8ede14ab603b900 for node:latest ...
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-14701224-concurrent-0 via runner-fa6cab46-srm-1570491263-da01e8a0...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/alejandroteixeiraconsultoria/my-awesome-response/.git/
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/alejandroteixeiraconsultoria/my-awesome-response
 * [new branch]      NodeApp    -> origin/NodeApp
Checking out e1235047 as NodeApp...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Building the app"
Building the app
$ echo "Calling npm "
Calling npm 
**$ npm update**

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /builds/alejandroteixeiraconsultoria/my-awesome-response/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

+ http-errors@1.6.3
+ cookie-parser@1.4.4
+ express@4.16.4
+ morgan@1.9.1
+ debug@2.6.9
+ pug@2.0.0-beta11
added 165 packages from 606 contributors and audited 305 packages in 7.972s
found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Job succeeded
```

As you see, my projects went perfectly with a default project.

[**Here is my example project**](https://gitlab.com/alejandroteixeiraconsultoria/my-awesome-response) with two different branches created on gitlab.com.

> If I were you, I would try to re-generate the runners key and to
>   disable shared runners and enable them again in order to check if
>   something went wrong in your project. If this does not work, just
>   re-creating a new project from scratch. This seems to be some kind of
>   bug in some of the versions. Maybe it just happened for some time and
>   get back again.

I hope at least this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your help and this valuable insight. Indeed "my" runner is `72989761`, I haven't cheked if this can be configured (which runner for which project) but I think not. Btw I've forked your project, ran the CI and it works.... using the same runner! So I think that it is not a global runner issue but moreover in the scope of my project only. I will delete the repo and create a new one.

Comment: So I created a new repo and pushed my project to this repo. CI ran successfully, using the same runner as mentionned above.

Comment: I was preparing you the commands in a big explanation. I wil add it in some minutes. !!!

Comment: I haven't cheked if this can be configured (which runner for which project) but I think not. You can assign tags to filter wich runner will be used and if you create a dedicated one.

Comment: Didn't change anything, and now it is working as well for my initial project, with "your" runner (` ed2dce3a`). Strange behavior!

Comment: I'd bet that this particular shared runner is not well configured. Also using an own runner in a local environment helps to detect those behaviours.