# Gitlab.com CI error: gitlab-runner-build: not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a very simple project in PHP. Mostly static content; little PHP code and no DB connections. I'd still like to have a deploy button in Gitlab.com. The production code is hosted in a plain ubuntu VPS.

I have this CI configuration to make a pull from the server when a deploy is made to the branch production:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy1:
  stage: deploy
  image: ubuntu
  only: 
    - production
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes --quiet openssh-client
  script:
    - echo "Passing..."
  after_script:
    - rm /tmp/ssh_key.pem
```

(I chopped the script part just to make sure there wasn't anything wrong there)
When I manually run the job I get this:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu ...
Using docker image sha256:d70eaf7277eada08fca944de400e7e4dd97b1262c06ed2b1011500caa4decaf1 for ubuntu with digest ubuntu@sha256:fff16eea1a8ae92867721d90c59a75652ea66d29c05294e6e2f898704bdb8cf1 ...
Preparing environment
00:01
/entrypoint: line 21: exec: gitlab-runner-build: not found
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit code 127. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

I've been fighting hard with it but couldn't get it to work. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Hope you find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238756/gitlab-ci-under-gitlab-com-system-failure-starting-container-process

Comment: Thanks! I tried creating a new repo as well as with other images (PHP, busybox, etc). I'll to play a bit with the runners (enabling and disabling).

Comment: I tried disabling and re-enabling shared runners to no avail. The funny thing is that when I disable the shared runner the task won't run because there's no runner active, yet the runner ece86343 isn't listed as a shared runner in the config.

Comment: I just checked: I set up the same script in another website in the same Gitlab.com account and the issue is there too (same runner). I wanna suspect a faulty runner but who knows...